# how to check for duplicate entry before update in php + mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

check for duplicate "username" field

case :

if user wants to update record other than username field (like firstname or whatever) and i used simple select query to check for duplicate like

```
"SELECT * from user where username = $username"
```

and check count than it will return count 1 because user name already exist (in same record)

case :

if user change username (it is unique now) and check for duplicate using same query than it returns 0 and it works fine

so if user doesn't change username than query above breaks

so i changed query like:

```
"SELECT * 
   FROM user 
  WHERE `username` = $username 
    AND user_ID != $uid" (here user_ID is primary key)
```

so it will not check current record so, is it correct or not ?

**EDIT :**

 my project is based on mvc ,modal have global function like

```
insert($tablename,$condition)
```

```
update($tablename,$condition)
```

Etc
and update funciton works like

create sql query (dynamically based on $condition)

Execute query with $result = $query->execute();

and

```
 if ($result) {
   $msg = 'true';  
 } else {
     $msg = 'false';
 }

  $data = array(
    'result' => $msg,
      'query' => $sql,
     'eventType' => 'Update'
   );
  return $data;
```

so how can i catch duplicate entry exception (i mean on which colum it occured (when multiple unique key exist))

Comment: You have an uneven number of quotation marks

Comment: And '==' isn't a thing in MySQL

Comment: it's doen't matter, i just want to know about logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do SQL is to have the structure enforce the contrants:

If you want a unique user name, declare a unique key on it.
`ALTER TABLE user ADD UNIQUE KEY username_uniq(username)`

Don't try to detect it up front, that will always be subject to race conditions.

Catch the duplicate key error exception when and `UPDATE`/ `INSERT` is done which violates the constraints.

Comment: just wanted to know if i don't have database access than my logic is correct?

Comment: no. no. its not.